# Ubuntu server. Дать доступ к MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, сервер, port

Установил MySQL на свой домашний ubuntu server. С самого сервера могу подключится через root пользователя к MySQL.

1 Вошел в нее, создал нового пользователя:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'мойПароль';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0,00 sec)  


mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| admin            | %         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

2 Далее настройка файла /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Текст файла:

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
skip-character-set-client-handshake

[client]
default-character-set=utf8
port = 2508

[mysqldump]
default-character-set=utf8
```

3 Перезагрузил

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

4 Переадресовал порт 2508 на роутере на машину сервера (Делал так же для Transmission и SSH. Все работает)

5 Через Workbench с компа в в этой же сети (что и сервак) не могу присоединится по

- внешнему ip : порт 2508 (Работаю этим вариантом по SSH, с другим
  портом естественно)
- внутреннему ip сервера : порт 2508

  - пробовал другие порты (3306)
  - пробовал удалять строчку "port = 2508" из файла my.cnf
  - пробовал добавлять строку bind-address = 0.0.0.0 в поле client

на netstat запрос получаю это:

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      1384/mysqld
```

Искал в интернете, там вообще никто порт не настраивает. Ну правда и про подключении из вне там не говорят. Не пойму что не так делаю.

Comment: В конфиге параметр bind-address есть ? У вас сейчас mysql запущен только на 127.0.0.1 надо поставить для этого параметра значение 0.0.0.0 что бы он на всех IP машины слушал

Comment: дописал в поле client строку "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" перезапустил сервис, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: И netstat так же пишет localhost ? это странно ... хотя может это оно так только выглядит. флаг `n` netstat добавьте что бы IP в имена не превращал

Comment: sudo netstat -n -tap | grep mysql

Comment: Возвращает только 1 строку. `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1092/mysqld`

Comment: Может нужно не в этот файл писать? Или писать не после `[client]`? В примерах из интернета видел файлы my.cnf уже с комментами и настройками. А у меня он почти пустой был. (Весь файл я скинул в вопросе) Или в новых версиях нужно как то иначе делать. Сайт http://help.ubuntu.ru/ не помог

Comment: У меня `bind-address=0.0.0.0` в блоке `[mysqld]`

Comment: сейчас посмотрим...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @Mike, нужно было писать в блок [mysqld]

Весь код файла /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
skip-character-set-client-handshake
#Для доступа из вне
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#Для замены стандартного 3306 порта
port = 2508

[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqldump]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Comment: И да. У пользователя `admin` не прописались права. Возможно из-за того, что забыл `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` прописать...